# how to save downloaded files to external storage

Tags: android

i have created an android application to download an image and save it to external directory but the application downloads the file and saves it to internal directory.
this is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/extSdCard/prateek");
            if(dir.exists() == false){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

           // File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
            File file = new File(dir,"downloaded_file.png");

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```html
String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File dir = new File(exStoragePath + "/prateek/");
```

Also include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to create a file and write "Hello world" in it. This file will be stored in /myDir directory.

You should add

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

to your manifest for this to work.

```
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/myDir");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        File outFile = new File (myDir, "myFile");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        out.write("Hello world");
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "File successfully created to "+outFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("debug", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: file NOT created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/extSdCard/prateek");
```

If I am right the above code of yours will give you path as "mnt/sdcard/storage/extSdCard/prateek" so instead of using root.getAbsolutePath() directly give the path "/storage/extSdCard/prateek" and 
Its also not a good practice to store in external card since in kitkat version and some other phones it will not provide external card it will assume internal memory as extsdcard

Comment: the above code gives me the path as: "/storage/emulated/0/prateek/download_file.png"

Comment: pls check the log and tell me the path of File file = new File(dir,"downloaded_file.png"); file.getAbsolutePath();